# How to call a rest API every n seconds?

Tags: firebase, api, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function which will put the number of views a YouTube video has in it's title. It is a https function so I have to call it every 28 seconds to keep the title as accurate as possible (28 seconds due to usage quotas). So my question is how can I call my function every 28 seconds.

I can't use pub-sub functions that firebase provides because I don't have access to a credit card. Currently I am using cron-job.org to call the function every minute but they don't provide anything more frequent.

Comment: Look into using Cloud Tasks to schedule future invocations of an HTTP function.  https://cloud.google.com/tasks

Comment: @Doug Stevenson  I looked in to it but it requires billing enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I need something that takes less than a few minutes in Cloud Functions, I typically use a simple `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

For example:

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {

      setInterval(() => {
        // do your thing every 28 seconds
      }, 28000); // 28 seconds

      res.send("ok"); // end the function after 1 minute
    }, 60000); // 1 minute
  })
});
```

Comment: This does have the limitation of only working for the max duration of the function, which can only be configured up to 9 minutes.  After that, it would have to be triggered again.  Also bear in mind that it costs money while the function is idle for 28 seconds, even if it's not doing anything.

Comment: 1) this runs for one minute, so well belong the maximum time. 2) agreed, but it's the only way I know how to do this without entering a credit card. If you know another way, I'd love to see an answer with it. ;-)

Comment: To run this *persistently, autotonomously* every 28 seconds, without a credit card?  A database trigger could trigger itself. I don't recommend this for production apps though.  https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack/blob/master/backend/functions/src/index.ts#L27

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. Would you have the client write to the database every 28 seconds then? That's also totally fine of course, although I'd probably use a Callable function in that case.

Comment: No, the function writes to the database to trigger itself - see the source.  There would just need to be one triggering event, perhaps through the console, to kick it off.  Note that it can be toggled on and off using a location in the database.

Comment: Sounds like a great alternative answer. :)

Comment: This won't work for me since it will easily go over the free execution time for cloud function. Still thanks for the idea

Comment: @Rohit You might be asking more than the free tier can offer.  It's meant for prototyping and learning, not for running production systems.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I think you are right. I will accept this answer since it seems like this is the best possible currently.